# Can the gravity of one entire galaxy slow down an astrophysical jet emitted from its central black hole?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, relativistic-jets

Let say we are talking about our Milky way and Sagittarius A* emitted a astrophysical jet. If the galaxy was 150 000 ly wide would its gravity with dark matter included eventually slow down that jet keeping in mind that gravity of a disk loses strength slower than a sphere as a black hole is?

Comment: Anything at all will slow down anything else at all, by gravitational attraction, if they are initially moving apart. So the answer is yes. But perhaps you are looking for a more thorough answer, with order-of-magnitude estimates or something like that. If so, then maybe make the question a bit more descriptive, to state more fully what you want to find out.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Can this be a result of astr.jets https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/article/milky-way-giant-gas-bubbles-visible-light

Answer (score 3):

No.

These jets are jets because they are faster than the escape speed of the various relevant objects (central black hole / Active Galactic Nucleus / host galaxy). Thus, gravity is not relevant in slowing it down. For order of magnitude, the escape speed of the Milky Way galaxy is about 650km/s, but these jets are relativistic, i.e. one or two orders of magnitude faster.

Instead, jets are slowed down by [Ram pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_pressure) as they encounter the intergalactic gas. This is why they "puff up" (rather than fall back on a parabolic orbit). Classic example is the jet from M87:

[image]